# [XSLT]: Remove string in XSLT

Tags: string, xslt, removeclass

I have the string "[test]" in xsl. I need to remove this brackets in the xsl. how can i achieve this in XSL. Please help.

i know this can do it, but how can i remove '[' with below code,

```
   <xsl:call-template name="string-replace-all">
     <xsl:with-param name="text" select="$string" />
     <xsl:with-param name="replace" select="$replace" />
     <xsl:with-param name="by" select="$by" />
   </xsl:call-template>
```

Please help to remove '[' and ']'

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the [translate()](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#function-translate) function.

Example...

```
<xsl:call-template name="string-replace-all">
 <xsl:with-param name="text" select="$string" />
 <xsl:value-of select="translate( $text, '[]', '')" />
</xsl:call-template>
```

Answer (score 6):

xsl 2.0

```
replace('[text]','^[(.*)]$','$1')
```

xsl 1.0

```
translate('[text]','[]','')
```

or

```
substring-before(substring-after('[text]','['),']')
```

Any of these will do what you want with varying failure modes. Note the second example will return something regardless of what the input is, but will strip all the brackets in the input. The third example will only return a string if it has an initial left bracket and a terminal right bracket, otherwise it will return an empty sequence.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to replace one symbol to another, you can use translate function (XSLT 1.0, 2.0), but if you want to replace strings, you can use common template for MSXML and other XSLT processors:

```
<xsl:template name="replace-string">
    <xsl:param name="text"/>
    <xsl:param name="replace"/>
    <xsl:param name="with"/>
    <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test="contains($text,$replace)">
        <xsl:value-of select="substring-before($text,$replace)"/>
        <xsl:value-of select="$with"/>
        <xsl:call-template name="replace-string">
          <xsl:with-param name="text" select="substring-after($text,$replace)"/>
          <xsl:with-param name="replace" select="$replace"/>
          <xsl:with-param name="with" select="$with"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
      </xsl:when>
      <xsl:otherwise>
        <xsl:value-of select="$text"/>
      </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>
```